# BLS signatures in the G-valued Random Oracle Model

Tags: signature, pairings, group-theory, bls-signature

[This paper on semi-generic algorithms](http://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2010/6477543/6477543.pdf) considers

["non-standard properties of the employed hash function"](http://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2010/6477543/6477543.pdf#page=15).

For [BLS signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLS_%28cryptography%29#The_scheme) whose main group is $G$, I'm curious what can

be shown when the hash function is a $G$-valued random oracle.

Is there a known [semi-generic](http://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2010/6477543/6477543.pdf#page=5) attack that is faster than just

ignoring the signing oracle and solving for the private key?

Is there a known lower bound for generic attacks that is better than the

bound that follows from the reduction to computational Diffie-Hellman?